# Pros and cons of backhand serve in squash

Tags: technique, squash, serve

What are the pros/cons of backhand serve in squash, in comparison to "regular" underhand serve?

Comment: Here are three [pros](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNX1WbBolu0) of the backhand serve on the forehand side, but the real test is: can you locate the accent? :) (And I would guess a con is accuracy.)

Comment: @aufkag do you play squash yourself?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I have played somewhat regularly, but this was a long time ago, and not at any level. (I am not qualified to write an actual answer, if that's what your after. E.g., I cannot confirm the third pro.)

Answer (score 5):

Advantages of the backhand serve on your forehand side

- getting quicker to the center of the court
- easier to watch the ball & opponent as you are facing it when moving to the center

Cons could be accuracy, less power as compared to a forehand serve.

Comment: I think the less acute angle of the shot as you are hitting the ball closer to the centre line also makes it easier to 'hug' the side wall with your serve.